# Simplify mesh by merging and filling holes

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

I have a rather complex planar mesh that I want to simplify (reduce number of faces) and fill the holes.

I have very little experience with Blender, but I have tried to use
- Mesh > Faces > Fill
- Modifier > Add Modifier > Decimate
- Mesh > Vertices > Merge
- Tools > Mesh Tools > Smooth Vertex
- Mesh > Clean up > Limited Dissolve

None of these helped, could someone point me in the right direction?

File can be downloaded here: http://www.horgvegen.no/barge_plane_org_0.1.blend

[image: Mesh with 2304 Verts, 2304 Edges and 768 Faces]

Comment: can you attach the file for detail investigation

Comment: Updated the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken a look at your Blend file, and I first noticed that your mesh is quite messy. In these cases, using operations as you have mentioned (Merge, Fill, Decimate, Dissolve) will only worsen the problem.

Due to the messiness of the object in question, if possible, I would recommend rebuilding the mesh using clean, quad-based geometry.

First, in top view (**Numkey 7**), add a new plane over top your existing object (**Shift + A** > **Mesh** > **Plane**)

Next, move the plane along the **X** axis to the left edge of your mesh (**G then X**)

[image: 1]

In edit mode (**Tab**), begin to move the vertices to the shape of the mesh. To select vertices, verify that you are in Vertex Select Mode (**Ctrl + Tab** > **Vertex**).

When you have shaped a section of the mesh, you can then extrude the edge of the plane to the right to add more detail. Use **Ctrl + Tab** > **Edge** to select whole edges then use **E** to extrude and repeat the previous vertex shuffling procedure.

[image: 2]

Use **Ctrl + R** to add new loops to existing sections of  your mesh. With these methods you can add as much or as little detail to your new mesh as you like.

Here is a low-detail example I was able to match in under a minute:
[image: New Mesh Working]

Comment: Thank you CGEffex for pointing me in the right direction how I should approach this messy mesh. I appreciate the effort you took to post descriptive images and hotkeys along with it. This file was created based on an extraction from a NawisWorks file and came out like this after importing it as .obj

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this result

[image]

If yes then there are many overlapping faces. I have deleted some overlapping faces and edges and got the result. You have to do some cleanup. Hard to explain

[image]

Comment: -1 Your result is quite messy itself and "You have to do some cleanup. Hard to explain" is a non-answer.

Comment: @CGEffex i have mention that there are overlapping faces that to be cleanup

Comment: Deleting the overlapping faces is a good start, but you should elaborate on "cleanup".

Comment: Thank you ateks for providing a cleaned up version of my file. I would really appreciate if you could explain shortly what you did to clean it up.